# Proxy API not working

Tags: crossrider

I am trying to use Crossrider's proxy API.  I just copied the code from the example provided, but it doesn't seem like my proxy is being used at all when I navigate to whatismyip.com.  I have a proxy running on 127.0.0.1:8877 and the code I am using is:

```
var whiteListDomains = ["whatismyip.com", "myglobalip.com"];
var proxyServer = "127.0.0.1:8877";

appAPI.proxy.set({ whiteListDomains: whiteListDomains, proxyServer: proxyServer });
```

I also tried:

appAPI.proxy.set({
        pacScript:
            "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {if (/whatismyip.com$/.test(host)) return    'PROXY 127.0.0.1:8877;'; return 'DIRECT'; }"
    });

This is the script I put in the background.js right in the appAPI.ready event. I am using Chrome. Is there anything special I need to do?  Can you please see if there is something I am missing?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided, I'm guessing the **Proxy** plugin was not added to the extension; hence in the extension's **My Project** panel, click **Add plugin**, select the **Proxy** plugin, and add it to your extension.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thank you for the useful information.  I didn't at first realize I needed to add a plugin.